# Drop tables from Command prompt in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

How to drop tables in a database from command prompt for SQL Server?

Comment: I googled your question, and got plenty helpful resources. What did you try yourself?

Comment: I googled it many times....but it is SQL server.....Through SQLCMD I have  taken BackUp and Restore. But not able to drop tables from Restored DB through SQLCMD...DROP command!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean using sqlcmd..? For example, maybe...

```
sqlcmd -S YourServerName -d "YourDatabaseName" -Q "DROP TABLE [YourTableName];"
```

If you need to specify your Username (and possibly password), then it's -U (and -P) respectively.

Comment: Yiepee.....Done Dude.....I corrected ------ sqlcmd -S <> -U <> -P <> -d "test1" -Q "DROP TABLE test1;"                 Thankyou @Larnu.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use the `drop table` syntax:

```
DROP TABLE mytable;
```

Comment: Ha Ha....I want to fire the command from CMD to sql server. From 500 tables i have to drop 50 tables(kind of automation work).